# Weird issue with [cell viewWithTag:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I've just analyzed the whole my iPhone app and I get a **Logic Error**.

```
UILabel *first_label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *second_label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];

[first_label setText:@"text"];
[second_label setText:@"text"];

NSLog(@"%@", first_label); // it exist
[first_label setFrame:CGRectMake(first_label.frame.origin.x, 10, 10, 10)];
```

I get this issue:

> The receiver of message 'frame' is nil and returns a value of type 'CGRect' that will be garbage

If i change:

```
[first_label setFrame:CGRectMake(first_label.frame.origin.x, 10, 10, 10)];
```

with

```
[first_label setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

he's happy. Is it normal? I can get the label without problems and I can use it everywhere, but when I try to get its frame it says that issue. Have you ideas?

Comment: Don't know. Probably it's an XCode issue. Only when you get the label with `[cell viewWithTag:]`.

Comment: how are you creating your cell? are you using `[cell addSubview:first_label]` or `[cell.contentView addSubview:first_label]`?

Comment: I don't. I use a custom UITableViewCell created in Interface Builder and I assign the tag to that, even in IB. Probably if I would fix this I should create the UITableViewCell programmatically.

Comment: basically, if a view is not yet part of the view hierarchy, it's `frame.origin` property will be useless. my idea is that your label's frame isn't recognized because you fetch label as `viewWithTag`. I would suggest creating a cell programatically and then accessing its properties directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyzer just sees that there is no place where you're adding the view with tag 1 in your code, and thats why

```
UILabel *first_label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
```

would probably return nil. Just set the breakpoint there and check the return value. If it is not nil, then probably analyzer doesn't understand something in your code, cause it's also not perfect.

Comment: I set the tag in the XIB file, because I use a custom UITableViewCell created in Interface Builder.

Comment: Probably if I would fix this "warning" I should create the UITableViewCell programmatically.